# Manage a few Linux servers at once

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cluster

I have a small cluster that consists of a few Linux nodes. There's a shared NFS, and I have the same user account with shared SSH keys on all nodes, but other than that each node has it's-own file system and configuration.

I want to be able to control the configuration of all nodes from a central node. A typical configuration consists mostly of config files, both in the user dir and in `/etc` or `/opt`. Occasionally I also need to install the same packages on all nodes or run other shell commands.

This is a small cluster that hardly justifies enterprise-level automation systems or other complex installations. Is there a different way that you have tried and tested, preferably lightweight and open-source? Or even based on BASH/SSH hacks directly? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for Cluster Middleware software or a mechanism for executing SSH commands across multiple terminals at once?

Comment: Are you admin-ing from a Windows or Linux PC ?

Comment: A configuration management tool like http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-open-source or http://www.getchef.com/chef/ seems what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Saltstack. It's flexible, scalable, lightweight and free.

http://www.saltstack.com

Comment: I can't even find a product list let alone a link to a free version of this software. Could you give some more detail to your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**[Ansible](http://ansible.com)** should do the trick if you're controlling them from Linux or Mac OS X with homebrew. Windows isn’t supported for the control machine. The Linux nodes need to have SSH and Python, but since most Linux distributions install Python by default, you're probably already covered. All you'll need to do is to [install](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#getting-ansible) ansible on the master, which should be easy.

Watch the 23 minutes [quick start video](http://www.ansible.com/resources) to get a better idea. I also recommend having a look at the [Introduction To Ad-Hoc Commands](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_adhoc.html) section from the documentation:

- Run the command on all servers in a group, in this case,
  atlanta, in 10 parallel forks:

  ```
  $ ansible atlanta -a "/sbin/reboot" -f 10
  ```
- Ensure a package is installed, but don't update it:

  ```
  $ ansible webservers -m yum -a "name=acme state=installed"
  ```
- To transfer a file directly to many different servers:

  ```
  $ ansible atlanta -m copy -a "src=/etc/hosts dest=/tmp/hosts"
  ```
- Ensure a service is started on all webservers:

  ```
  $ ansible webservers -m service -a "name=httpd state=started"
  ```

There are also some [examples](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples) of playbooks.

Answer (score 1):

For running commands you can use a tool that can run a command on multiple SSH servers

There are some of them:

1. [pssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/)
2. [Cluster SSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/)

Both available in Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

Try **[Expect](https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/expect)** scripts. They are a great way to automate running the same tasks on multiple machines.

With expect scripts, you will not have to manually log into each machine and perform the same task again and again. I use to for things like changing passwords of a user on all machines, running check scripts on each machine etc.

Comment: I don't see why this aswer got downvoted...